# How do I add another object to my singleton code?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Here is my singleton code:

```
@synthesize listOfSites;

+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t dispatchOncePredicate = 0;
    __strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
    dispatch_once(&dispatchOncePredicate, ^{
        _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return _sharedObject;
}

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        listOfSites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

It's pretty much textbook... however, I want to add another array, similiar to "listOfSites" (call it "listOfReadings").  The code that says "if (self)" confuses me.

How do I add another array to this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (self) {` does nothing but to verify that the `[super init]` has worked - and that it hasn't return `NULL` or anything...

Other than that, you can do this normally, like :

- declare a `listOfReadings` array (as an ivar/property?)
- set it up

  ```
  listOfReadings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  ```

  **or**

  ```
  listOfReadings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
  ```

  **or** *(if it's a `property`)*

  ```
  [self setListOfReadings:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil]];
  ```

---

**Example :**

```
-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        listOfSites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        listOfReadings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

after having declared the new `NSMutableArray` in your `.h` file :

```
NSMutableArray* listOfReadings;
```

Comment: Thank you so much... that's what I thought it would be, but then wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(id) init {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    listOfSites    = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    listOfReadings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
return self;
```

}

if (self) in other words means "If current object is successfully created then..."